# ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Tags: oracle, listener

I tried to start the listener and do a dbstart, but it looks like it is still saying "Oracle Not available". Maybe the dbstart didn't work. Any suggestions would help me.

```
[user@fedora16 bin]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
[user@fedora16 bin]$ echo $ORACLE_SID
orcl
[user@fedora16 bin]$ cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora 
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

orcl =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0

[user@fedora16 bin]$ cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora 
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

ADR_BASE = /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0

[user@fedora16 bin]$ dbstart $ORACLE_HOME
[user@fedora16 ~]$ lsnrctl start orcl

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 04-MAR-2012 09:04:19

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0/diag/tnslsnr/fedora16/orcl/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     orcl
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                04-MAR-2012 09:04:19
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0/diag/tnslsnr/fedora16/orcl/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully

[user@fedora16 bin]$ ps -ef | grep  '\(ora\|smon\|lsnr\)'
user  2405     1  0 08:46 ?        00:00:00 /home/user/app/user/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr orcl -inherit
user  2553  1611  0 08:49 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto \(ora\|smon\|lsnr\)

[user@fedora16 bin]$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Mar 4 08:46:29 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: scott
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbstart` will only start databases that have the third parameter in the `oratab` file set to `Y`. Check the value in that file.

<strike>You also don't need to pass the `ORACLE_HOME` as an argument; not sure if you actually meant to pass the SID, but anyway, the home is taken from the `oratab` too.</strike>

The script itself says that it should only be executed as part of the system boot procedure, e.g. from a script run during boot from an `/etc/rc*.d` directory. The `$ORACLE_HOME` parameter that's passed in is only used to start the listener; the home for each database is taken from `oratab`.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10839/strt_stp.htm), `dbstart` is deprecated in favour of Oracle Restart (in non-RAC environments) in 11g Release 2; I guess that means you should use `crsctl start has` to start the listener and database from then. That also uses the third `oratab` value to decide whether to start the database.

Comment: In the dbstart file, it says 
`# usage: dbstart $ORACLE_HOME`

Comment: Yes, I changed the file /etc/oratab for orcl from N to Y, and then commented out some part of dbstart and now it started successfully. Thanks!

Comment: @tech_learner - hmm, haven't used it for a long time (and it's deprecated in 11gR2), but I thought the home argument was optional. Well, as long as you got there...

Comment: Even though that answers the question, my question would be why are you using dbstart if on 11gR2?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had faced the below issue:

> ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
>
> ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
>
> Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory

It is not allowing me to connect sql, I checked the active user sessions from `V$sessionn` and one of user occupied more session.  In order to fix it, I killed the active user session